# Converting a graph to a directed graph with order of the nodes defined by post-order traversal

Tags: python, graph

**Background:**
I'm implementing an algorithm from the paper [Polygon Area Decomposition for Multiple-Robot Workspace Division](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=51D9679503B28E964F70480B9167426D?doi=10.1.1.55.7496&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and one of the steps is to represent a polygon as a graph. This is done by splitting a polygon to convex parts that will become the nodes of the graph, and the edges of the graph will represent those parts that touch each other:

[image]

What I'm required to do by the algorithm is:

1. to have the nodes of the graph ordered as in [post-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_search_of_binary_tree) traversal;
2. to be able to get for a given node all the nodes that go before it in the ordering and that are accessible from the given node without entering the nodes that go after in the ordering (NetworkX calls these nodes [ancestors](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.ancestors.html));
3. to keep information about the touching sides of the polygon parts in some manner so that I wouldn't have to recalculate them again every time.

To convert a polygon to a graph was fairly simple. The problems arise when I want to satisfy the given requirements. I wrote the following function that would convert a simple graph to a directed graph with the necessary ordering and which would allow me to easily get ancestors of any given node.

**Code:**

```
import networkx as nx


def to_ordered(graph: nx.Graph) -> nx.Graph:
    """
    Makes a directed graph out of the input graph.
    Nodes will be ordered in a depth-first-search post-ordering.
    :param graph: graph representing convex parts of a polygon
    :return: directed graph with touching sides as edges' attributes
    """
    ordered_graph = nx.DiGraph()
    ordered_nodes = list(nx.dfs_postorder_nodes(graph))
    ordered_graph.add_nodes_from(ordered_nodes)
    directed_edges = (sorted(edge, key=ordered_nodes.index)
                      for edge in graph.edges)
    ordered_graph.add_edges_from(directed_edges)
    for *edge, side in graph.edges.data('side'):
        if edge in ordered_graph.edges:
            ordered_graph.edges[edge]['side'] = side
        else:
            ordered_graph.edges[edge[::-1]]['side'] = side
    return ordered_graph
```

**Usage example:**

```
import networkx as nx

# Creating an example input graph:
edges = [(5, 4), (5, 1), (3, 5), (2, 3), (6, 2), (1, 6)]
sides = list(map(str, edges))  # example data to keep as attributes
graph = nx.Graph()
for edge, side in zip(edges, sides): 
    graph.add_edge(*edge, side=side)
nx.draw(graph, with_labels=True)
```

[image]

```
# converting to a directed graph with desired characteristics
ordered_graph = to_ordered(graph)
nx.draw(ordered_graph, with_labels=True)
```

[image]

```
# new graph is ordered according to the post-order graph traversal:
print(ordered_graph.nodes)
# [4, 3, 2, 6, 1, 5]

# finding nodes' ancestors:
for node in ordered_graph.nodes:
    print(node, nx.ancestors(ordered_graph, node))
# 4 set()
# 3 set()
# 2 {3}
# 6 {2, 3}
# 1 {2, 3, 6}
# 5 {1, 2, 3, 4, 6}

# accessing edges' attributes:
for edge in ordered_graph.edges:
    print(edge, ordered_graph.edges[edge])
# (4, 5) {'side': '(5, 4)'}
# (3, 5) {'side': '(3, 5)'}
# (3, 2) {'side': '(2, 3)'}
# (2, 6) {'side': '(6, 2)'}
# (6, 1) {'side': '(1, 6)'}
# (1, 5) {'side': '(5, 1)'}
```

**What I want reviewed:**
As you can see from the given example the code works correctly, but I find my code too complicated for such a simple task. I especially dislike the part with copying the attributes from one graph to another. Most probably I simply miss some NetworkX functionality that would help me write it much more concisely. Any comments on this or any other matter are welcome.